# CUDA with C/C++ Compilation fails

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I am trying to integrate CUDA code with my existing C++ application. As instructed on some web side, I need to have a "file.cu" where in I have a wrapper function which does the memory allocation on the GPU and launch kernel. I followed that advise but, I am not able to compile the code now.

file.cu

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void preComputeCorrelation_gpu( int * d )
{
    //I shall write the kernel later once I am confirmed that CUDA code works
    cudaDeviceProp prop;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties( &prop, 0 );
    printf( "name = %s\n", prop.name );
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <cuda.h>

#define __CUDA_SUPPORT__

#ifdef __CUDA_SUPPORT__
// Defination to be found in "cudaWrap.cu"
extern void preComputeCorrelation_gpu( int * d );
#endif


int main()
{
//code to read d from the file and other initialization
int * d;
.
.

#ifdef __CUDA_SUPPORT__ 
    fprintf( stderr, "GPU Computation starts" );
    // Defination to be found in "cudaWrap.cu"
    preComputeCorrelation_gpu( d ); 
#else
    fprintf( stderr, "CPU Computation starts" );
    preComputeCorrelation( d );
#endif


.
.
//more code

return 0 ;
}
```

Now, I put following commands to compile the code

```
$ nvcc -c cudaWrap.cu <br/>
$ g++ -I /usr/local/cuda-5.0/include -L /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib -o GA_omp GA_dev_omp.cpp main_omp.cpp data_stats.cpp cudaWrap.o
```

Compilation fails and I get the following message after the 2nd command. Although the 1st command works.

```
cudaWrap.o: In function `preComputeCorrelation_gpu(DataSet*)':
tmpxft_00001061_00000000-3_cudaWrap.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `cudaGetDeviceProperties'
cudaWrap.o: In function `__cudaUnregisterBinaryUtil()':
tmpxft_00001061_00000000-3_cudaWrap.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `__cudaUnregisterFatBinary'
cudaWrap.o: In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll_43_tmpxft_00001061_00000000_6_cudaWrap_cpp1_ii_f8a043c5()':
tmpxft_00001061_00000000-3_cudaWrap.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterFatBinary'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How to I sort this out really?

Comment: You forget to link the libcudart.so. Add -lcudart at the end of the g++ command and it should compile.

Comment: @mkuse: if would be helpful if you add your solution as an answer. In a couple of days you will be able to accept it and that will get the question off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is that linking of the ordinary c++ code and cuda code needs to be done with libcudart.so

Compilation should look some like --

```
$ nvcc -c cudaWrap.cu 
$ g++ -lcudart -I /usr/local/cuda-5.0/include -L /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib -o GA_omp GA_dev_omp.cpp main_omp.cpp data_stats.cpp cudaWrap.o
```

In this case, cudaWrap.cu contains the cuda code. main_omp.cpp contains the main() and there are some other application files that need compiling too.